# how to get grid children by its row and column in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Width="150" Height="50" x:Name="Btn1" Content="Button1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Button Width="150" Height="50" x:Name="Btn2" Content="Button2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button Width="150" Height="50" x:Name="Btn3" Content="Button3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Button Width="150" Height="50" x:Name="Btn4" Content="Button4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

C# code in wpf

```
Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(LayoutRoot,0);
```

With above code i can get the First child of the grid(LayoutRoot).But i want to get grid child by it's rows or columns. What should i do for that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You usually should not use the `VisualTreeHelper`, ever.

Answer (score 19):

Filter the `Grid.Children` based on what [`Grid.GetRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.getrow.aspx) and [`GetColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.getcolumn.aspx) returns for every child.

e.g.

```
var itemsInFirstRow = LayoutRoot.Children
                          .Cast<UIElement>()
                          .Where(i => Grid.GetRow(i) == 0);
```

Comment: @ChandruA: Seen the example? In any case you are probably doing something wrong if you need to find UI elements, your code probably needs more [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx).

Comment: var itemsInFirstRow = LayoutRoot.Children.Where(i => Grid.GetRow(i) == 0); It is showing error.

Comment: You would have to write `LayoutRoot.Children.Cast<UIElement>().Where(i => Grid.GetRow(i) == 0)`.

Comment: I agree with H.B. This isn't a great approach. What happens if later a row or column is added to or removed from the grid. Would you or another developer remember or know to go change that hard coded number?