# Specific control for a specific DataType

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a List which contains different types of objects:

```
    List<object> myList = new List<object>();
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    myList.Add(date);
    int digit = 50;
    myList.Add(digit);
    myList.Add("Hello World");
    var person = new Person() { Name = "Name", LastName = "Last Name", Age = 18 };
    list.ItemsSource = myList;

    public class Person
    {
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public string LastName { get; set; }
         public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to see them in a `ListBox` with different kinds of controls. For instance: `DatePicker` for `DateTime`, `TextBlock` for `string`, `TextBox` for `Person`'s Name and LastName...

Is it possible to do this task with `XAML`?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Yes this is possible, use the DataTemplateSelector: http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

Comment: @FlorianGI that's completely unnecesary and involves unneeded code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.DataTemplates"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="DataTemplates"
        Height="300"
        Width="300">
  <Window.Resources>

    <!-- DataTemplate for strings -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- DataTemplate for DateTimes -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
      <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataTemplate.Resources>
      <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=.}" />
    </DataTemplate>


    <!-- DataTemplate for Int32 -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
      <Slider Maximum="100"
              Minimum="0"
              Value="{Binding Path=.}"
              Width="100" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
 public partial class DataTemplates : Window
    {
        public DataTemplates()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var myList = new List<object>();
            myList.Add(DateTime.Now);
            myList.Add(50);
            myList.Add("Hello World");

            DataContext = myList;
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, there's no reason **at all** to use code to manipulate UI elements in WPF (except some very very specific cases)

**Edit:**

Note that you don't usually create a `DataTemplate` for classes inside the `System` namespace (such as `System.String`. This is only to give you an example. If you really needed this you would probably have to create a `ViewModel` for each type.

Comment: Didnt thought about this, very nice solution. ;)

Comment: yes it works. I found a small problem. I put those three DataTemplates into ListBox.Resources. Now if you open a DatePicker all the dates are in TextBoxes. Can I say this DataTemplate only for this ListBox?

Comment: Let me know if I am wrong. Isn't it hard coding? So do I have to override the DataTemplate all the time if I have some other controls which has string in it.

Comment: @Dilshod see my Edit note. As I mentioned, you don't usually do this. The proper way to implement this would be to use a proper ViewModel for each type, and leaving the `System.XXX` types alone.